# Fatal error: Call to undefined method User_m::get() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\controllers\admin\user.php on line 18

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i open the link 'http://127.0.0.1/cms/index.php/admin/user/edit/1'
this is my user_m model

```
<?php

class User_m extends CI_Model{

    protected $_table_name = 'users';
    protected $_order_by = 'name';
    public $rules = array(

        'email' => array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
            ),

        'password' => array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
            )
        );
    public $rules_admin = array(

        'name' => array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
            ),
        'order' => array(
            'field' => 'order',
            'label' => 'Order',
            'rules' => 'trim|is_natural'
            ),
        'email' => array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__unique_email|xss_clean'
            ),

        'password' => array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|matches[password_confirm]'
            ),

        'password_confirm' => array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|matches[password]'
            )
        );

    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();

       }

       public function login()
       {


            $user = $this->db->get_where('users', array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' =>$this->hash($this->input->post('password'))

                ), TRUE);

            if (count($user)) {
                $data = array(
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'loggedin' => TRUE,
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            }
       }

       public function logout()
       {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
       }

       public function loggedin()
       {
            return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
       }

       public function hash($string)
       {
            return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
       }


}
```

this is my user controller

```
<?php
class User extends Admin_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['users'] = $this->db->get_where('users');
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }

    public function edit($id=NULL)
    {

            $id == NULL || $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
            $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/edit';
            $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }   

    public function delete($id)
    {

    }



    public function login()
    {
        $dashboard = 'admin/dashboard';
        $this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);
        $rules = $this->user_m->rules;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if ($this->form_validation->run()==true) {

            if ($this->user_m->login() == TRUE) {
                redirect($dashboard);
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'That email and password combination does not exit');
                redirect('admin/user/login', 'refresh');
            }
        }

        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $this->data);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->user_m->logout();
        redirect('admin/user/login');
    }
}
```

this is my edit file.

```
<div class="modal-header">
       <h3><?php echo empty($user->id) ? 'Add a new user' : 'Edit user' . $user->name; ?></h3>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      <?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($this->session->userdata, TRUE) . '</pre>'; ?>
      <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open(); ?>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('email'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Log in', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      </div>
```

this is my index file

```
    <section>
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit', '<i class="icon-plus"></i> Add a user'); ?>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php if(count($users)): foreach ($users->result() as $user): ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->email); ?><td>
                    <td><?php echo btn_edit('admin/user/edit/'. $user->id); ?><td>
                    <td><?php echo btn_delete('admin/user/delete/' . $user->id); ?><td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">We could not find any user</td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Check you code is properly formatted before post question

Comment: You don't have `get()` method in `User_m` model. If you would like to use `get()` method of `DB` class it has to be coded since it is not `CI_Model`'s method you want to inherit, if I am right.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent construct area on controller try loading model that way all the function in that controller have access to the model else you can load model in the edit function

I can see there is no **get function** in model also.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_m'); // Filename should be User_m.php same as class
}
```

Or

```
public function edit($id=NULL)
{
    $this->load->model('user_m'); // Filename should be User_m.php same as class
    $id == NULL || $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

Also I see your IP address is loaded in your url. If your using CI3 versions in the config.php you must set this value.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

To

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
```